# Is there a faster way to do this Cholesky factorization in Rcpp/c++?

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra, rcpp, armadillo

This is a problem arose in my Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) algorithm. And I feel this problem is quite commonly encountered especially in hierarchical Gaussian models. Hence it would be great if there is a much more efficient solution. So the problem is like this:

I have many positive integer vectors `xi`, for `i` from 1 to n, a p.s.d. matrix `A` and a p.s.d. matrix `B`. For every `xi` I want to compute the following Cholesky factorization:

> chol( kron( diagmat( xi ), A ) + B )

So `kron( diagmat( xi ), A ) + B` is the covariance matrix for a multivariate Gaussian and I want to sample from this Gaussian hence need the Cholesky factorization of it. The dimension for `A` and `B` are not small and I have a large `n` hence computing the above Cholesky factorization for all `xi` is really time-consuming. Below is the `Rcpp` function I wrote using `RcppArmadillo`:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <Rmath.h>
#include "RcppArmadillo.h"
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace arma;
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat test_C(mat A, mat B, mat X){
  int n_x = X.n_cols;
  int d_B = B.n_rows;
  mat sample(d_B, n_x);
  mat mS_chol_inv;
  for (int i = 0; i < n_x; i++){
    mS_chol_inv = inv(trimatu( chol(kron(diagmat( X.col(i) ),A) + B) ));
    sample.col(i) = mS_chol_inv*randn(d_B);
  }
  return(sample);
}
```

I also test the computational efficiency using the following code comparing it to its R counterpart:

```
test_R <- function(A,B,X){
  n_x <- ncol(X)
  d_B <- ncol(B)
  res <- sapply(1:n_x, function(x){
    mS_chol <- chol( kronecker( diag(X[,x]),A ) + B )
    return( mS_chol%*%as.matrix( rnorm(d_B) ) )
  })
  return(res)
}

# Simulate Data
R1 <- matrix(rnorm(24*2),24,2)
A <- R1%*%t(R1) + 0.1*diag(24)
R2 <- matrix(rnorm(264*2),264,2)
B <- R2%*%t(R2) + 0.1*diag(264)
X <- matrix(rpois(11*2178, 5),11,2178)

res <- benchmark(res_R <- test_R(A, B, X),
             res_C <- test_C(A, B, X),
             columns=c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative"),
             order="relative",
             replications = 2)
```

And the result is as follows

```
> print(res) 
                      test replications elapsed relative
1 res_R <- test_R(A, B, X)            2  18.920    1.000
2 res_C <- test_C(A, B, X)            2  20.724    1.095
```

As can be seen, a single run is approximately 10 second, and this is simply not feasible in a MCMC algorithm. Also, since the `chol()` dominates the computational complexity, the improvement of using `Rcpp` over pure `R` is trivial. But maybe I did not write the most efficient code? So any advice?

Since the matrix inside `chol()` is very structured and the only thing that is varying is `xi`, maybe there is some algebra trick that I do not know that can solve this efficiently? I have posted this as a linear-algebra question under **Mathematics** and here is the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684978/faster-cholesky-factorization-of-diag-mathbfx-i-otimes-mathbfa-mat). Unfortunately so far I have not received any solution, people do point out that this is embarrassingly parallel.

Any advice on code/algebra will be helpful! Thanks ahead for your time.

Comment: The actual work is done in the LAPACK/BLAS libraries -- and both code path call the same.   On several OSs you can simply plug+play and drop other BLAS libraries in.  Debian and Ubuntu give you Atlas ("tuned" / tuneable) and OpenBLAS (multithreaded) and you can also look into Intel MKL.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks! Will definitely try to parallel my code.

Comment: Also note that in _most_ use cases for Choleski decompositions in order to draw multivariate normals, the correlation structure is known so you do the decomposition only once before your loops.  Sure you cannot do that here?

Comment: Two things prevent me from doing that: 1. I am updating the correlation structure within my MCMC hence will need to re-calculate the factorization in each iteration; 2. The model has a complex hierarchical grouping structure and each group has its unique covariance matrix (and there are many groups, i.e., the `xi`'s). The reason that I feel there might be some **shortcut** is that these covariance matrices are highly structured and the only thing that varies between groups is the values of `xi`'s. Hence I am suspecting that there could be some faster way to do the computation.

Comment: Ack, I see. That may require thought rather than just coding...

Comment: I'm obviously very late to the party, but unfortunately changing any of the components (xi, A, B) will change the covariance in nontrivial ways, meaning that the updates are going to be complex. It may just be easier if B is rank 1. But the sum is what makes it difficult. @Bayesric any chance you have a reference for the kind of model that produces this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use Microsoft **R** from [here](https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/open/), artist formerly known as RRO. It integrates with multi-threaded Intel MKL library (same place to find and install it) and on Intel hardware matrix operations are quite fast.

Disclaimer: YMMV

Answer (score 1):

**(Rcpp) Eigen or Armadillo for Cholesky?**

I can't post this as a comment to @zdebruine's answer, but I'd like to figure out what's the best practice for Cholesky using RcppArmadillo/Eigen.

Note: this SO question is the top Google search result for "fastest Cholesky using Armadillo or Eigen". I think it's useful for people to evaluate pros and cons of both

Here's a first attempt at a benchmark (the CPU here is an AMD Ryzen 9 5950X). I'll edit and update based on suggestions.

`sessionInfo()` returns:

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.5.281/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_rt.so
```

Source:

```
arma_source <- '
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

//[[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat arma_chol(const arma::mat& X){
  return arma::chol(X, "lower");
}
'

eigen_source <- '
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
#include <RcppEigen.h>

//[[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::MatrixXd eigen_chol(const Eigen::MatrixXd& X){
  Eigen::LLT<Eigen::MatrixXd> Xllt(X); 
  return Xllt.matrixL();
}
'

Rcpp::sourceCpp(code=arma_source)
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code=eigen_source)


nr <- 2000
Gen <- matrix(rnorm(nr^2), ncol=nr)
X <- crossprod(Gen)

RhpcBLASctl::blas_set_num_threads(1)
RhpcBLASctl::omp_set_num_threads(1)

rbenchmark::benchmark(
  L_arma = arma_chol(X),
  L_eigen = eigen_chol(X),
  U_R = chol(X),
  replications=100)
```

Results:

```
     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1  L_arma          100   4.770    1.056     4.635    0.136          0         0
2 L_eigen          100  12.908    2.856    12.768    0.141          0         0
3     U_R          100   4.519    1.000     4.403    0.116          0         0
```

I'm not familiar with ways to make the Eigen code more efficient. I find it odd that there's a difference at all. The disparity grows if I allow for multithreading, as Eigen only runs on 1 thread in my current config.
The fact that R's `chol()` is the same as arma's is unsurprising, as both use MKL's BLAS

If we add `#define EIGEN_USE_BLAS` we get the following

```
     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1  L_arma          100   5.556    1.039     4.958    0.597          0         0
2 L_eigen          100   6.257    1.170     5.621    0.631          0         0
3     U_R          100   5.347    1.000     4.555    0.790          0         0
```

which pretty much makes everything use the same BLAS functions

Comment: Thanks for a concrete benchmark!  Unfortunately, I can't reproduce your results.  For `relative` measures for `L_arma, L_eigen, and U_R` I'm getting `4.303, 1.000, 4.437` (Intel I5-5300), `3.700, 1.000, 5.431` (Intel I5-8400), and `3.877, 1.000, 4.850` (Intel Xeon E5-2683 v3), `6.039, 1.000, 3.537` (Intel Xeon Gold 6230), all using `libRblas`.  In all cases Eigen was faster than arma, although my fastest time was slightly slower than your slowest `elapsed` time.  YMMV, especially on HPC systems, but I'm more interested in "average" computing backends for general-purpose analysis.

Comment: by libRblas do you mean the default blas that ships with R? then arma wouldn't be using openblas/mkl in that case, which would explain the difference

Comment: as a follow up: on Apple's M1, I get figures similar to yours when using R's default blas, but matching mine when using vecLib. I guess Eigen does its own thing whereas armadillo uses whatever R is using.

Comment: try adding a preprocessor directive `EIGEN_USE_BLAS` to your header.  https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html.  I don't think Eigen will look for a different BLAS than it's own without that directive.

Comment: I updated the answer -- but as expected then everything is going to use the same thing, which again points to the differences in the other scenarios being due to Eigen by default doing its own thing, whereas arma/R looking at the linked BLAS, which may be better or worse than Eigen's implementation depending on the setup. what I haven't seen though is Eigen being faster than arma if arma is linked to a fast BLAS

Comment: very interesting, thanks for doing that benchmark.  And thanks for exploring this issue so thoroughly, rather than my hand-wavy answer (although the Eigen BLAS is definitely better than the "average" BLAS, and thus Armadillo in "average" cases).

Answer (score 0):

You would significantly benefit from using **RcppEigen** instead.

This is because:

- Eigen has a faster Cholesky solver
- Eigen allows subviews by reference and has inbuilt optimization for solving Cholesky from these subviews
- Eigen has loads of under-the-hood optimizations specifically for the LLT decomposition that you may be able to benefit from without your knowledge.

In terms of performance gains you can expect, I can only speak to my use cases, where I decompose matrices up to 100x100 using LLT decomposition, but Armadillo was almost **50% slower**!

Look at the source code for Eigen and Armadillo! Armadillo runs every cholesky through a generic template to LAPACK/BLAS "auxiliary" libraries. Eigen runs a decision tree internally to choose an optimized implementation and then directly solves by reference to internal structures in-memory as much as possible.

**tl;dr**: For decompositions, you won't easily beat Eigen.

Comment: once you link R to a decent LAPACK/BLAS library, I don't see how Eigen can beat Armadillo in speed. Armadillo also has other advantages: in my experience it outputs errors more gracefully than Eigen (which makes the R session crash), and has a much MUCH better and clearer documentation. Eigen is more flexible with the subviews and other specialized features such as the sparse solvers, though.

Comment: @mkln agreed that Armadillo is easier to work with than Eigen (more graceful errors).  Also agreed on the documentation clarity -- Conrad has done an exemplary job.  However, disagreed on the speed statement.  Eigen uses lazy evaluation, and extensive meta-templating (far more than Armadillo).  Many BLAS applications may be comparable between Armadillo and Eigen, but Cholesky decompositions are not one of those.  That said, I'm always inclined to see more benchmarks, other than what I've seen first-hand.

Comment: can you produce an example? I find it very hard to believe that Eigen does any better than a good blas specifically at Cholesky.

Comment: If I had time I would, but I can only speak from my work developing fast NMF and NNLS implementations (RcppML R package), where I've seen for NNLS that a Cholesky decomposition in Eigen was about 40% faster than Armadillo on a number of machines for problems with 10-1000 variables, and for systems with <10 variables it did comparatively even better.  Dense subviews were roughly 20% faster.   It would be nice to have a more technical benchmark, but this varies so much by data, machine, etc.  Eigen can take advantage of MKL BLAS routines.  Further benchmarking might be a good Q for @ggael.

Comment: armadillo also uses MKL BLAS if that's what R is linked to. my expectation is that the timings are going to be pretty much exactly the same between the two, if both use the same BLAS backend

Comment: I've added an answer with a small benchmark. happy to edit following suggestions to improve eigen's performance. I'm very interested in this kind of problems myself.